# How to manually extract context or span from incoming http request in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, open-telemetry

I trying to migrate my `Node.js` application from `jaeger-client` to `@opentelemetry/*` packages

In my `Node.js` application i have a simple http server and i want to create span on each response.

With `jaeger-client` i did it in the following way:

```js
import { FORMAT_HTTP_HEADERS } from 'opentracing';
import { initTracerFromEnv } from 'jaeger-client';

const tracer = initTracerFromEnv(/* some options here */);

// app is expressjs app
app.get('/home', req => {
  const rootSpan = tracer.startSpan('response', {
    childOf: tracer.extract(FORMAT_HTTP_HEADERS, req.headers),
  });

  // ...make child spans of rootSpan
});
```

I want to connect my root span of response with spans from other application, that performs request to my `Node.js` application server. About the same as I would do it with `jaeger-client`.

How can i make it with OpenTelemetry instead of `jeager-client` and `opentracing`? Is it possible to create child spans manually, without auto instrumentations?

Comment: What does "create span on each response" mean?  What is a "span" in this context?  Right now, I don't think anyone can understand what your question means so it's likely to accumulate downvotes and/or close votes and may end up getting closed.  Please clarify what your question means.

Comment: @jfriend00 clarified the details a bit

Comment: What is the `tracer` object?  What specific module does that come from?

Comment: @jfriend00 is JaegerTracer (interface from 'jeager-client' npm package, in my case i get it from initTracerFromEnv() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the Context Propagation by extracting the parent context from the request headers and creating the child span with it, as follows:

```
const opentelemetry = require('@opentelemetry/api');
const {SpanKind, ROOT_CONTEXT} = require("@opentelemetry/api");


app.get('/home', req => {
  // Get incoming context from headers
  const remoteCtx = opentelemetry.propagation.extract(ROOT_CONTEXT, req.headers);

  // ...make child spans of remoteSpan

  // Create child span passing parent context 
  const childSpan = tracer.startSpan(
    'childSpan',
    remoteCtx
  );

  // ... Do important stuff

  
  // End the span
  childSpan.end();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but in opentelemetry tracer there is no option "childOf", also there is no extract method

Comment: The `childOf` is from your code, I just copied over. ChildOf is available for the OpenTracing shim, but you don't need it. You need the context part.

Comment: I've updated the answer just with plain OpenTelemetry.

Comment: thanks but how do i link my root span to the request span of a remote app that accesses my app via HTTP?

Comment: @dima.krutoo it is written in the answer. You first get the `rootSpan` context, and then you pass it to the new span at its creation.

Comment: To get the context of a remote span, you need to use the extract method available here: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/blob/main/packages/opentelemetry-core/src/propagation/composite.ts#L88

Comment: Excuse my stupidity, but could you please provide an example of code using the extract method?